# Openerp - notify users by message when a product has been created

Tags: messaging, openerp-7

I am customizing OpenERP.  I need to display a notification message to all "Purchase Managers" as soon as a product created by user.

I saw a message is created under **settings** -> **Email** -> **Messages** by saying "Product Created".  However it is not displaying for the managers under main menu **Messaging** -> **Inbox**.

I want put this message as notification for managers.  However, not able to find any good documentation in Google.

Correct me if I am missing any basic logic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to inherit the product module and override the create method like this:

```
def create(self, cr, uid, datas, context=None):
    new_id = super(class_name, self).create(cr, uid, datas, context=context)
    self.log_prod(cr, uid, new_id, context)
    return new_id

def log_prod(self, cr, uid, ids, context=None):
    product = self.pool.get('product.product').browse(cr, uid, ids)
    msg = "Product %s has been created" % product.name
    msg_id = self.message_post(cr, uid, ids, body=msg, context=context)
    notif_obj = self.pool.get('mail.notification')
    all_groups = self.pool.get('res.groups')
    h1m_group = all_groups.browse(
            cr,
            uid,
            all_groups.search(
                    cr,
                    uid,
                    [('name','=','Access Rights')],
            ))
    for ids in h1m_group[0].users:
        notif_obj.create(
                cr,
                uid,
                {
                    'partner_id': ids.partner_id.id,
                    'read': False,
                    'message_id': msg_id,
                },
                context=context)
    return True
```